# ¿Por qué no se pueden enviar los parámetros desde android con Volley a MySQL con PHP?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webservice, volley

Tengo el siguiente error a la hora de enviar los parametros con la librería de volley, a lo que he leído es que a la hora de obtener el txtNumeroPedido da error

```
E/Volley: [346] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
              at com.example.dell.localizacion1.MainActivity$7$override.getParams(MainActivity.java:138)
              at com.example.dell.localizacion1.MainActivity$7$override.access$dispatch(Unknown Source:87)
              at com.example.dell.localizacion1.MainActivity$7.getParams(Unknown Source:12)
              at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:475)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:245)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:219)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:97)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf3ac7c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xda9dbc30)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf3ac7c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xda9dbc30)
```

Mi código de la clase ActivityMain es el siguiente

```
package com.example.dell.localizacion1;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LocationManager ubicacion;
    Thread hilo;
    int j = 1;
    boolean ejecutar;
    EditText txtNumeroPedido, txtLongitud, txtLatitud;
    Button btnUbi;


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Button btnEmpezar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEmpezar);
        Button btnUbi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUbi);
        final Button btnFinalizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinalizar);

        //registrarLocalizacion();
        localizacion();

        ejecutar = true;
        hilo = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (ejecutar) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            txt.setText(" " + j);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        sleep(5000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        };

        btnEmpezar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    hilo.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btnFinalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ejecutar = false;
            }
        });

        btnUbi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.0.5:8080/localizacion1/ingresarPedido.php");
            }
        });

    }

    private void localizacion() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            },1000);
        }
        TextView txtLongitud = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLongitud);
        TextView txtLatitud = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLatitud);
            ubicacion = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location loc = ubicacion.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(ubicacion != null) {
                Log.d("Latitud", String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
                Log.d("Longitud", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
                txtLongitud.setText(String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
                txtLatitud.setText(String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
            }
    }

    private void ejecutarServicio(String URL){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Operación exitosa.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("numeroPedido", txtNumeroPedido.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("longitud",txtLongitud.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("latitud",txtLatitud.getText().toString());
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

El código PHP que ejecuta la consulta es

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$numeroPedido = $_POST['numeroPedido'];
$longitud = $_POST['longitud'];
$latitud = $_POST['latitud'];

$consulta = "UPDATE pedido SET numeroPedido = '".$numeroPedido."', 
longitud = '".$longitud."', latitud = '".$latitud."' WHERE numeroPedido = '".$numeroPedido."'";
mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

y por último el xml es el siguiente

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.386"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.235" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEmpezar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:text="Empezar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="76dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="159dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFinalizar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnEmpezar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="finalizar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="176dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="159dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNumeroPedido"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
        android:text="1"
        tools:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLongitud"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="166dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="43dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLatitud"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtLongitud"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnEmpezar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUbi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="101dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: El error te lo da porque no has declarado la variable txtNumeroPedido y esta es nula. Añade lo siguiente en el onCreate(): txtNumeroPedido =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumeroPedido);

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Ahora mismo tu problema no es de Volley (ya veremos si la petición funciona o no). Por lo pronto tienes un NPE porque no estás creando una referencia a tres de tus `TextView` en el contexto. El mensaje de error es claro: *`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference.`* Para tenerlos disponibles tienes que poner esto en el `onCreate` de la Activity: `txtNumeroPedido= findViewById(R.id.txtNumeroPedido);  txtLongitud= findViewById(R.id.txtLongitud); txtLatitud= findViewById(R.id.txtLatitud);`

Comment: Hola @CristhianLeyva el problema es que no obtienes las referencias de los EditText como indica A.Cedano, por esta razón al llamar los métodos getText() marca error.

Answer (score 0):

tiene pinta de que txtNumeroPedido es null está vacío, prueba a hacer lo siguiente para averiguar más acerca de cuál es exactamente el problema.

Intena utilizar Logs:

> Log.i("Error Res TXTNUMPEDIDO: ", txtNumeroPedido.getText().toString());
>   Log.i("Error Res TXTLongitud: ", txtLongitud.getText().toString());
>   Log.i("Error Res TXTLatitud", txtLatitud.getText().toString());

Lo insertas dentro de new Response.**ErrorListener** en el Volley: o en **getParams**()
Tendrás que importar Importar Log.

```
new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Error Res TXTNUMPEDIDO: ", txtNumeroPedido.getText().toString());
                Log.i("Error Res TXTLongitud: ", txtLongitud.getText().toString());
                Log.i("Error Res TXTLatitud", txtLatitud.getText().toString());
}
```

Luego copia y pega el Log que te aparece en Android Studio.

Te recomiendo los Logs: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es

Answer (score 0):

El problema es un NullPointer al no obtener las referencias de los `EditText`,

```
 EditText txtNumeroPedido, txtLongitud, txtLatitud;
```

estos elementos existen en tu layout, pero debes obtener su referencia dentro del método `onCreate()`, realizalo de esta forma:

```
Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtNumeroPedido = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumeroPedido);
        txtLongitud= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLongitud);
        txtLatitud= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLatitud);

        ...
        ...
        ...

}
```